# hibernate save takes a long time

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to import a list with 1000 entries.

It takes me more than an hour. Looking into the logs, I see a lot of

```
09:59:52 DEBUG [http-apr-8031-exec-13] AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareCollectionFlushes(184) | Dirty checking collections
09:59:52 DEBUG [http-apr-8031-exec-13] Collections.processReachableCollection(195) | Collection found:
```

the Collections.processReachableCollection(195) grows exponentially as hibernate makes more and more inserts.

For example, the first time a record is saved I see about 17 processReachableCollection
somewhere down the end of the log file I see about 200 of them. I think that is what is slowing it down.

I am using the OpenSessionInViewFilter. I cannot change that right now, as I will have to go through the whole application and fix any issues with LazyInitException.

Is there a way I can tell hibernate not to do dirty checking and just do a simple insert

Comment: Are you modifying collections when you create your new objects ? Are you using annotated fields or annotated accessors ?

Comment: I am not modifying the collections. I am just doing a simple insert. One of the values I insert is a foreign key for which I need to fetch another object. this object has a bunch of collection loaded eagerly. I looks like hibernate is keeping all the new and old collections in session and updating all of them. I am using annotated fields.

Comment: If you are using a single session/single transaction everything in the session (first level cache) is being checked for updates (i.e. dirty checking). What you want to do is to manually flush after x records and after the flush clear the session. Tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_batch_processing.htm

Comment: Thanks, I did an entitymanager.clear() and that seems to have fixed the issue. Now i can insert 1000 entries in 10 sec as oppose to more than an hour

Comment: Be good to be able to tell Hibernate - don't check the caches, I'm sure its a new object. and that implicitly puts responsibility on me if its not.